# Printing function with a window alert in javascript

Tags: javascript

Assuming this code is correct, how can i get it the print the output into a window alert with the click of a button?

```
function passgen() {
  var length = 10,
    charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789?#$",
    retval = "";
  for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
    retval += charset.charat(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
  }
  return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `button` to your HTML, assign an `onclick` handler and replace `return` with `alert` to get a popup message holding the generated string.

I also fixed a typo for you. It's `charAt`, not `charat`.

```js
function passgen() {
        var length = 10,
            charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789?#$",
            retval = "";
        for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
          retval += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
        }
        alert(retval);
      }
```

```html
<button onclick="passgen()">Generate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is just a callback on button click.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
         <script>
           function passgen() {
              var length = 10,
              charset =    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789?#$",
              retval = "";
              for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
                retval += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
              }
              return retval;
           }
         </script>
      </head>
    <body>
      <input type="button" onclick="window.alert(passgen())" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fix `charset.charat` to be `charset.charAt`,
secondly you need to use `alert()` to call alert on the screen.

```js
function passgen() {
  var length = 10,
    charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789?#$",
    retval = "";
  for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
    retval += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
  }
  return retval;
}

function alertOnScreen() {
  alert(passgen());
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alertOnScreen()">Click me</button>
```